# Accessing data in r from list with multiple vectors

Tags: r, list, vector

```
A <- list(X = c(Z = 15))
```

How do I access 15 in the above example

Comment: you could do `A$X[['Z']]`

Comment: Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using a combination of list access syntax along with vector access syntax:

```
A <- list(X = c(Z = 15))
A$X["Z"]

Z
15
```

Above `A$X` refers to the element in the list named `X`, which happens to be a vector.  Then, `A$X["Z"]` accesses the element in the vector named `Z`, which is the value 15.

Answer (score 1):

Can also access it with indices:

```
A[[c(1, 1)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
A[[1]]
```

This gets the first "component" of the list.

```
 A[[1]]
 Z 
15
```

Or if you want to go step by step, then:

```
A[1][[1]]

     Z 
    15
```

Comment: if I have to call 'X' only meaning the name only and not the lower order, then what should be the code?

Comment: @ambrishdhaka Often hard for me to figure out without actual data,. I suppose `my_list["X"]` should work(this will not work if the list is "deep" ie > 1 layer.

Comment: I was looking for solutions as I am blocked to post new questions. Otherwise, definitely would have posted my question. Although, I have figured out the difference between the nested list and the named nested list. It helped me sort out.